# How should values that "don't exist" sometimes be handled as input data?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm currently training an agent to learn how to fight in a shooting game.

I'm using the bullet positions of the agent's opponent as one of the features. The features "don't exist" when the opponent isn't firing a bullet.

What should I substitute the feature with when the opponent of the agent doesn't fire a bullet? Right now, I'm considering using "0", but are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to input a non-existing feature is a common problem in machine learning models. Entering `0` and `0` could mean the position `{ x: 0, y: 0 }`.

But if you'd input "nothing", that still would be `0` (because `nothing * weight = 0`).

The best you can do is figure out what works best through trial and error. I could think of a few options:

- If your network supports negative activation values (range: `-1, 1`), you should try to input it as `-1`.
- I don't think the learning model will have a hard time if you'd just input `0` as input, like you proposed.
- Add an extra input feature, 'bullet exists'. `0` if there is no bullet, `1` if there is a bullet. Then just input `0` for the x and y coordinates.